# Equivalent operation to remainder operator for handling values below the minimal allowed

Tags: c++, c

I have a set of indices in a loop from 0 to 5. If user specifies an index  above 5, ex 7, index 7-6=1 should be returned. If an index is specified below 0, ex -2, index -2+6=4 should be returned.

In the first case we can use remainder operator to handle the values above 5:

```
int inputValue = 7;
int result = inputValue%6;
```

However is there similar operation to elegantly handle the cases where the index specified is below 0? A hacky solution would be:

```
if (inputValue < 0)
   result = inputValue+6;
else
   result = inputValue;
```

This only handles the values greater or equal than -6

Comment: You can calculate the remainder % and then, if negative, add 6

Comment: You can do something like ((a%b) +b)%b to be generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mod a negative number by six, you’ll get back a negative number, but you can just add six to it to get your positive remainder:

```
int result = (inputValue % 6) + (inputValue < 0? 6 : 0);
```

Or, using the fact that adding six to a positive remainder leaves a number with the same remainder:

```
int result = ((inputValue % 6) + 6) % 6;
```

Hope this helps!